# pandas - How to convert aggregated data to dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate

Here is a snippet of the CSV file I am working:

```
ID    SN            Age    Gender  Item ID   Item Name                Price
0,      Lisim78,      20,   Male,     108,   Extraction of Quickblade, 3.53
1,      Lisovynya38,  40,   Male,     143,   Frenzied Scimitar,        1.56
2,      Ithergue48,   24,   Male,      92,   Final Critic,             4.88
3,      Chamassasya86,24,   Male,     100,   Blindscythe,              3.27
4,      Iskosia90,    23,   Male,     131,   Fury,                     1.44
5,      Yalae81,      22,   Male,      81,   Dreamkiss,                3.61
6,      Itheria73,    36,   Male,     169,   Interrogator,             2.18
7,      Iskjaskst81,  20,   Male,     162,   Abyssal Shard,            2.67
8,      Undjask33,    22,   Male,      21,   Souleater,                 1.1
9,      Chanosian48,  35,   Other,    136,   Ghastly,                  3.58
10,     Inguron55,    23,   Male,      95,   Singed Onyx,              4.74
```

I wanna get the count of the most profitable items - profitable items are determined by taking the sum of the prices of the most frequently purchased items.

This is what I tried:

```
profitableCount = df.groupby('Item ID').agg({'Price': ['count', 'sum']})
```

And the output looks like this:

```
    Price
       count    sum
Item ID
0           4   5.12
1           3   9.78
2           6  14.88
3           6  14.94
4           5   8.50
5           4  16.32
6           2   7.40
7           7   9.31
8           3  11.79
9           4  10.92
10          4   7.16
```

I want to extract the 'count' and 'sum' columns and put them in a dictionary but I can't seem to drop the 'Item ID' column (Item ID seems to be the index). How do I do this? Please help!!!

Comment: what is you expected output

Comment: @Wen-Ben, i want the count and sum extracted and put into a dictionary but I can't seem to drop the Item ID column. When I do try to drop Item ID, I get an error - " 'method' object is not subscriptable.

Comment: It is better show us what is your expected output

Comment: I'm looking for a dictionary that will print key:values
{(4: 5.12),
(3 : 9.78),
(6:14.88),
(6:14.94),
(5:8.50),
(4:16.32),
(2,7.40),
(7,9.31),
(3,11.79),
(4,10.92),
(4,7.16)}

Comment: @KrithikaRaghavendran python doesnot allow duplicate keys in a dictionary as far as i know. :)

Comment: My CSV has many duplicate 'Item ID' values because it is a spreadsheet of purchased data. I need to group items by Item ID and then add their sum and get the count of those Item IDs. I know this is possible. I just need a method

Comment: Dictionary consist of a series of {key:value} pairs. In outcome you provided there is no key:value.      {(4: 5.12), (3 : 9.78), (6:14.88), (6:14.94), (5:8.50), (4:16.32), (2,7.40), (7,9.31), (3,11.79), (4,10.92), (4,7.16)}

Answer (score 0):

Dictionary consist of a series of {key:value} pairs. In outcome you provided there is no key:value.

> {(4: 5.12), (3 : 9.78), (6:14.88), (6:14.94), (5:8.50), (4:16.32),
>   (2,7.40), (7,9.31), (3,11.79), (4,10.92), (4,7.16)}

Alternatively you can create two lists: `df.count.tolist()` and `df.sum.tolist()`
And put them to list of tuples: `list(zip(list1,llist2))`